# Issues with the Documents in Mongoose (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm making a bot for discord but I'm having some issues with Mongoose. So what I want is basically, the user sends a message to save a Document with some of his info, but if there is already a Document with his info it will stop the process with return. So I tried this:

```
      function main(message){
        // So first user sends a message to store some data about him
        let author = message.author //this is discord.js syntax, basically it returns the author of a message
        let id = author.id //also discord.js syntax, returns the id from the user, in this case the author variable above
       
       let check = logUser.findOne({userId : [id]}).exec().then(res => {
            if (res) return true;
            else return false;
        })} // So if there is a Document with the id of the author of the message it will return true, else it returns false

        if (check === true) return console.log("This User has already a Document with his info saved"); 
//so if the user has already a Document with his info it will return and stop the action of saving his Data
//everything from this point is basic Mongoose Syntax, to make a Document with User data
        const theUser = new logUser({
            _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            userName : author.username,
            userId : author.id,
            currency : 0
        })
        theUser.save()

        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

        console.log(`User ${author.username} was stored into the database!`)
}
```

It fails in the if statement that checks if the user has a Document with his info already. I've tried multiple things but it doesn't work.
I think that the solution for this problem has to do with async functions but I'm not sure, and I don't know that much about async processes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your treating logUser.findOne as synchronous. Perform the check in findOne callback like so:

```
  function main(message){
    // So first user sends a message to store some data about him
    let author = message.author //this is discord.js syntax, basically it returns the author of a message
    let id = author.id //also discord.js syntax, returns the id from the user, in this case the author variable above
    
    logUser.findOne({userId : [id]}).exec().then(res => {
      let check = Boolean(res);
      if (check === true)
        return console.log("This User has already a Document with his info saved");

      const theUser = new logUser({
        _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        userName : author.username,
        userId : author.id,
        currency : 0
      });

      theUser.save()
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          console.log(`User ${author.username} was stored into the database!`)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    });
}
```

Are you purposely wrapping the id in an array? I don't know your schema but it seems odd and may contributing to your issues. `userId : [id]`

You may want to consider async/await to reduce callbacks. You can also look into using a unique index to avoid multiple requests in the future. Using a unique index will throw an error when trying to save the same document twice.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: About wrapping the id, actually it only works that way, if i don't wrap it, it will not recognize the variable.